# Is there any way to enable an 'Add More' button if only 4 out of 5 mandatory fields of the Form are filled by user?

Tags: angular

I am loading data from a json clob (stored in database table) onto my Angular 5 form. 6 out of a total of 10 fields are required fields. All these 10 form fields are dynamically generated in a loop. I have been able to enable and disable a Submit button using formgroup.valid. The Submit button gets enabled when all 6 required fields are entered by the user and gets disabled even if a single value is missing. This behavior works fine.

However, I need another 'Add more' button on the same form  that needs to  appear only when 5 fields (out of mandatory 6 for earlier Submit) are filled in. Is there any way I could use formgroup.valid with an exception of one field for 'Add more' button?

Greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have got your question correctly you need to check the value of entries and hide/show a button with it. in the following you can find an example of how to hide a button if the value of inputs are empty. You can ofc change the hide/show logic based on your needs.

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input #nameInput matInput placeholder="Name" required>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea #commentInp matInput placeholder="Leave a comment" required></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button type="button" [hidden]="nameInput.value==='' && commentInp.value===''"> Add More</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do this in my scenario where fields are being loaded from json dynamically and I am not able to determine the field ids (e.g #nameInput and #commentInp from the example) beforehand?